# catalyst app template toolkit different config per domain

Tags: perl, view, catalyst, template-toolkit

I'm building a [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org) application and I want to use [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) as my templating system. However, my application will be responding to many domains, and depending on the domain, it will display different content with different `Template Toolkit` configs. Essentially, if I have domain.com and domain2.com, I'd like each to have its own config. Does anyone know of an elegant way to do this while still being able to use `Catalyst`'s view feature? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

By putting this in the Root Controller, I've figured out that I can change the site wrapper in the config fro the `Template Toolkit` object. However, it just seems to use the initial wrapper located in `lib/myapp/View/HTML.pm` (I'm guessing because it's just using the wrapper that it was initialized with). Is there anyway to get it to recognize that I changed the wrapper for this request?

```
sub begin :Private {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    $c->view('HTML')->config->{WRAPPER} = $c->req->uri->host . '/site/wrapper';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to declare `WRAPPER` in each main template directly, rather than globally like that.

```
[%- WRAPPER c.req.uri.host _ '/site/wrapper.tt'; -%]
```

... as I find it allows for far more flexibility.

---

However...

Another option that I have had great success with is using a custom template path, so that domain specific versions of your templates can over-ride defaults, where they exist. This gives you enormous flexibility to inject variations of your code as required.

**=== MyApp::View::TT.pm ===**

```
sub process {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    # capture original path, identify host
    my @orig_include_path = @{$self->include_path};
    my $domain = $c->req->uri->host;

    # augment every path with domain/path
    @{$self->include_path} = map { ("$domain/$_", $_) } @orig_include_path;

    $self->SUPER::process($c);

    # revert path
    @{$self->include_path} = @orig_include_path;
}
```

The net result of which is that every call for a `WRAPPER`, a `PROCESS` or an `INCLUDE` will check for a domain specific version or produce the generic version, i.e.

```
[%- WRAPPER wrapper.tt -%]
```

will find `$domain/wrapper.tt` or fall back to `wrapper.tt` if there's no such file. This automatically extends to:

- foo/bar/baz.tt
- domain1/foo/bar/baz.tt
- domain2/foo/bar/baz.tt

Hope that's useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just historically the best idea might be something like: https://metacpan.org/release/Catalyst-TraitFor-Component-ConfigPerSite which provides the ability to specify configuration per site/host. Thus you can specify separate view/wrapper/db connection and etc.